# android EditText's background

Tags: android, background, android-edittext

I would like to set to my EditText [background](http://img9.imageshack.us/f/backgroundtext.png/) .

Hm ... I don't know even how to explain ....
When there is a lot of text vertical scroll enables ... 
I need to 'scroll' the background when user scrolls the text (Now I have that when user scrolls the text background is fixed, so text became crossed by lines of background)

Have you any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a drawable in xml like this for lines as mybackground.xml, where @drawable/divider will be your line image with the prefered space between lines

```
<bitmap android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:src="@drawable/divider"  
     android:tileMode="repeat" 
     android:dither="true"
/>
```

and set the following attributes in EditText control to adjust the

```
android:background="@drawable/mybackground"
android:lineSpacingExtra="Your Value" 
android:lineSpacingMultiplier="Your Value"
```

Comment: It just adding reapeatable background for edittext. But when user is scrolling the text (vertical scrolling) the  text is moving but the background left as is. It look not pretty... :(

Comment: consider making the height of the EditText as wrapcontent with minimum height set and put it inside a scrollview. that solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give [lineSpacingExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3alineSpacingExtra) and [lineSpacingMultiplier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3alineSpacingMultiplier) a try and then try to adjust the background image to it so it all fits as desired. Alternatively you can also try to play around with a 9-patch image and get it to repeat as desired but I'm not sure is this is going to work that way. Those are two options to try out maybe I can come up with more at a later point.

EDIT: It won't work with 9-patches.

Comment: I haven't understood, how lineSpacing can help me :( ... Can you provide some example, plz