# How to make background behind edittext scrollable

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am using an Edittext with an image behind it. But it is not scrollable as I continue to put the text the begining of the text is not visible to me.. I want to know how can I make it scrollable.

Comment: try to wrap them with scrollview

Comment: Please use the below link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176808/android-edittexts-background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in EditText XML tag:

```
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

If you would like a vertical scroll, define in your EditText XML tag:

```
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
edText.setScroller(new Scroller(myContext)); 
edText.setMaxLines(1); 
edText.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true); 
edText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```